# How to include variables in a string?

Tags: python, speech

I'm doing some coursework and I need to determine a character's name. This is what I have so far:

```
charOne=input("Please input your first character's name: ")
charTwo=input("Please input your second character's name: ")
```

So the user inputs the names, and now I need to ask the user to choose one of these characters.

```
chooseCharacter=input("What character do you want to use?"
```

I need to put the users charOne and charTwo into the question. Or some way need to make the user choose the user they want to use.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking here, can you go into more detail and show more of your code?

Comment: Yea, at the beginning the program asks what you want your name to be-
    charOne=input("Please input your first character's name: ")
    charTwo=input("Please input your second character's name: ")
So you write two names (e.g michael, and wade) now i need to ask the user to choose one of these characters
    chooseCharacter=input("What character do you want to use?"
and i  need to put the users charOne and charTwo into the question. or some way need to make the user choose the user they want to use.

Comment: sorry, @SuperBiasedMan thats my code, since i have to write 15 chars, hi :)

Comment: @MichaelWade Ok, then take a look at what Peter Wood linked above. There are two main ways to insert a variable into a string, that link shows them both and has discussion on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Python string formatting:

```py
charOne = input("Please input your first character's name: ")
charTwo = input("Please input your second character's name: ")

chooseCharacter = input("What character do you want to use? (%s or %s): " % (charOne, charTwo))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i was just messing with %s and didnt know how to use it! thank you very much! :D